# Replace src of img stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace src of 1st img tag with index 0 of attachments array, 2nd tag with index 1 so on and so forth without using jQuery. The html in stored inside a variable.

```
var body="<div dir="ltr">
             text above image
             <div>
               <img src="cid:ii_ksc42giw0" alt="IMG_20210814_124816.jpg" width="407" 
                  height="542"><br>
               <img src="cid:ii_ksc41siq0" alt="IMG_20210814_124816.jpg" width="407" 
                  height="542"><br>
             </div>
             <div>
               text below image
             </div>
          </div>"

var attachments = ['https://some-random-url-1', 'https://some-random-url-2']
```

Comment: [Obligatory HTML/regex link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454).

Comment: Ahh Tony, I miss him so

Comment: There **has** to be a clean dupetarget for this, but I haven't found one yet. If anyone does, please `@` me to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions to try to handle HTML is error-prone. Instead, use a parser. You seem to be doing this in a browser, so you can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(body, "text/html");
const images = doc.querySelectorAll("img");
for (let i = 0, len = Math.min(attachments.length, images.length); i < len; ++i) {
    images[i].src = attachments[i];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var body=`<div dir="ltr">
             text above image
             <div>
               <img src="cid:ii_ksc42giw0" alt="IMG_20210814_124816.jpg" width="407" 
                  height="542"><br>
               <img src="cid:ii_ksc41siq0" alt="IMG_20210814_124816.jpg" width="407" 
                  height="542"><br>
             </div>
             <div>
               text below image
             </div>
          </div>`;

var attachments = ['https://some-random-url-1', 'https://some-random-url-2'];

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(body, "text/html");
const images = doc.querySelectorAll("img");
for (let i = 0, len = Math.min(attachments.length, images.length); i < len; ++i) {
    images[i].src = attachments[i];
}

// ...put `doc` in the document, or use `outerHTML` if you
// need an HTML string from the result
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: FYI: `console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);` shows just the string that was parsed with the changes applied - since the original string had no html, head, body etc